# Problema ao fazer deploy de aplicação laravel no heroku

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, heroku

Estou com problema para fazer deploy no heroku com uma aplicação laravel, o heroku não esta enxergando as minhas páginas com extensão `.blade.php`.

Por exemplo:
 
`index.blade.php`

Mas se eu troco para `index.php` ele enxerga, alguém já passou por isso e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: E por quê o Heroku precisa "enxergar" esses arquivos? Eles não são tratados pelo próprio Laravel e servidos em HTML?

Comment: Entendi, bom eu nao sabia disso, vou fazer alguns testes baseados no que voce me disse, obrigado.